# Populate AEM forms dropdown field using data from a JSON file

Tags: aem

I have a JSON file - `options.json` which looks like this -

```
{
"option1" : "abc",
"option2" : "xyz"
}
```

I have saved this file in AEM's DAM.

I want AEM form's dropdown list to be populated using the values from this file. 
How do I achieve this?

Please note - entering path of this file in the `Items Load Path` field doesnt work.

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more detail? Do you mean AEM Forms the product by Adobe, do you mean forms in TouchUI author dialogs, forms on publishers?

Comment: I had this requirement sometime back, I am not an aem forms expert but seems its not possible to achieve this (with ootb components) server side, you can write code in jquery/js to make an ajax call to your json and populate dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided I assume that you want to do this in the Adobe product called `AEM Forms`.

Solution outline:

1. Create a REST service (could be a simple Servlet) that exposes the contents of the file as Json.
2. Create a new AEM Forms DataSource and configure your REST service.
3. Create a Form Data Model.
4. Configure Form Data Model to use DataSource.
5. Use Form Data Model in your Form component.

You can find the documentation for this here:

1. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/forms/using/creating-datasource-feature-video-use.html
2. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/forms/using/data-integration.html

Google will give you more links and examples.